# How to determine if a Salesforce trigger was fired because of a child record change?

Tags: apex, trigger

**Background**

According to the [Triggers and Order of Execution documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

> If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a
>   cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up
>   summary field in the parent record. Parent record goes through save
>   procedure.

Which means a child record change causes parent object to trigger.

I have an `Invoice__c` object and child `Invoice_Line__c` object.

**Questions**

1. Is there any way to determine if the `Invoice__c` trigger was fired due to a `Invoice_Line__c` record change? (without adding a `Invoice Line Count` roll-up summary field)

Comment: You could place a system.debug statement in the code to see if you are ever in doubt.

Comment: Is there any existing rollup-summary?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal there isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a Static variable in some class.

**InvoiceLineTrigger :**

```
Trigger InvoiceLineTrigger on Invoice_Line__c (){

    TransactionClass.isInvoiceLineTriggerCalled = true;

}
```

**TransactionClass :**

```
public class TransactionClass{

    public static boolean isInvoiceLineTriggerCalled = false;

}
```

**InvoiceTrigger :**

```
Trigger InvoiceTrigger on Invoice__c (){

    if(TransactionClass.isInvoiceLineTriggerCalled){ // Parent update due to child

    }

}
```